# Sequence proof(ratio test)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me solve this question? I was trying to verify that it was true first by testing values of $r$ and it appeared no matter what values I used it seemed to approach 1 at infinity.

Consider a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $a_n \geqslant 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = r$  for $r \in \mathbb{R}$.
Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if $r < 1$ and diverges if $r > 1$.

This result is known as the Root Test.

Hint: the proof is similar to that of the Ratio Test.

Comment: Read the proof given in a text book. We can help you if you get stuck.

Comment: This seems like a homework problem. Could clarify where you are stuck or struggling? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you mean $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ instead of $\sqrt{n}a_n$

Comment: yes I do, someone edited it

Comment: Do you think you could fix it? it won't allow me to edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s=(1+r)/2.$

If $0\le r< 1$ then $0<r<s<1,$ so for all but finitely many $n$ we have $(a_n)^{1/n}<s<1 ,$  and hence $0\le a_n<s^n,$ so $\sum_na_n$ converges by comparison to the geometric series  $\sum_ns^n.$

If $r>1$ then $r>s>1,$ so for all but finitely many $n$ we have  $(a_n)^{1/n}>s,$ and hence $a_n>s^n>1,$ so the rest is (I hope) obvious.

If $r=1$ then $\sum_na_n$ may or may not converge. For example $(1/n)^{1/n}$ and $(1/n^2)^{1/n}$ both $\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$ but $\sum_n (1/n)$ diverges and $\sum_n(1/n^2)$ converges.